# Set Custom Commands to programmatically created Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, commandbinding

I'm new to WPF and am trying to create an interface that builds itself from a XML file. The newly built interface contains different controls like textboxes, labels or buttons. And the last one gave me a headache for days, because every button shall get its own command.

Example XML Code for buttons:

```
ID="1001" GroupID="1" Control="Button" Content="Apply" Margin="2" Width="60"
```

And this is the method that defines each button:

```
public Button Button(XElement xElement, Button newButton)
{
    if (xElement.Attribute("Width") != null)
        newButton.Width = Convert.ToDouble((xElement.Attribute("Width").Value));
        
    if (xElement.Attribute("Content") != null)
    {
        string sContent = xElement.Attribute("Content").Value;

        //Here gets the button its command
        Commands Commands = new Commands();
        Commands.setCommand(sContent, newButton);
        newButton.Content = sContent;
    }
    return newButton;
}
```

The Content Attribute names the button and the function at the same time.

**Problem**: Basically I am trying to build a commands class that contains all possible commands. Each time a button is created the `setCommand(sContent, newButton)` method scans the `commands` class and sets up the matching command to this button via a Switch-Case statement.

And now each time the button is clicked the assigned command should fire.
But is it even possible to do it this way, or am I on the wrong track? Is there an easier solution to do this or am I just missing essentials of command binding?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish eventually? are you trying to build a UI dynamically from an xml?

Comment: how are you setting the command on button in setCommands()?

Comment: @Omribitan: Yes, that's the idea behind that.

Comment: @nit: That is the problem. The method should do it, but I don't know how.

Comment: If you are doing this for serialize/deseriailze purposes, you can use `XamlWriter` to do so, although I should note that you should NOT serialize the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you have your own commands defined that you want to bind to Buttons on your UI, then they should be exposed via `public properties in your VM or DataContext` of your UI.

Then once you have this arrangement in place, you can set the Command on button like below:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyCommand"); //Name of the property in Datacontext
button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Works fine! After a little workaround of the DataContext it does what it should. Thanks!